# Android - Pass a object to a view tag with Databinding

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to control some states of my views with their tags.

I have a `sealed class` with objects related with my views.

```
sealed class AuthFieldState: BaseFieldState(){
  object IdentifierFieldState: AuthFieldState()
  object NameFieldState: AuthFieldState()
}
```

And I'm passing this to view like this:

```
android:tag="@{AuthFieldState.IdentifierFieldState}"
```

But its showing me a build error:

> Could not find accessor AuthFieldState.IdentifierFieldState

Do you guys knows how can I handle this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tag cannot be an instance of object, it has to be a string.

```
    <!-- Supply a tag for this view containing a String, to be retrieved
         later with {@link android.view.View#getTag View.getTag()} or
         searched for with {@link android.view.View#findViewWithTag
         View.findViewWithTag()}.  It is generally preferable to use
         IDs (through the android:id attribute) instead of tags because
         they are faster and allow for compile-time type checking. -->
    <attr name="tag" format="string" />
```

I'm not sure what is your exact use case, but if you really need to do it in such a way as you described, you could do something like this:

```
sealed class AuthFieldState {
    object IdentifierFieldState: AuthFieldState() {
        override fun toString() = this.javaClass.simpleName
    }
    object NameFieldState: AuthFieldState()
}
```

and then in your xml import type and use it like this:

```
<data>
    <import type="com.yourpackage.AuthFieldState" />
</data>

...

android:tag="@{AuthFieldState.IdentifierFieldState.INSTANCE.toString()}"
```

Comment: I am stuck in the same error yet. I am trying to pass to a view some generic thing where a `MutableLiveData` that I have can manage the state of screen. Every field need a diff state